# Django: Unable to load template tags

Tags: django, templates, tags

I'm using Django 1.2.1 and I'm having problems trying to load my
template tags:

```
{% load mytags %}

TemplateSyntaxError at /myapp/

'mytags' is not a valid tag library: Template library mytags not
found, tried django.templatetags.mytags
```

It's defined in `myproject/myapp/templatetags/mytags.py`.

```
nate@nate-desktop:~/work/django-projects/myproject$ ls myapp/templatetags/
mytags.py  __init.py__
nate@nate-desktop:~/work/django-projects/myproject$ more
myapp/templatetags/mytags.py


from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def myclass(request):
    return request.path
```

I added 'myapp' to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and updated `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` (as
per a suggestion from StackOverflow):

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
   'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
   'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
   'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
   'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
```

When I start the server I see this warning message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/eggs.py:4:
UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/_mysql.so, but
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6 is being added to sys.path
```

When I try to import my module in the shell I also am unable to import it:

```
>>> from django.templatetags import mytags
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name mytags
>>> from myapp.templatetags import mytags
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named templatetags
```

Does this mean something is wrong with my path or setup?  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also have an `__init__.py` in the `myapp` directory?

Comment: Good question.  Yes, I do:

    nate@nate-desktop:~/work/django-projects/myproject$ ls myapp/
    __init__.py   models.py   templatetags  views.py
    __init__.pyc  models.pyc  tests.py      views.pyc

Comment: I am having difficulty entering the output from 'ls'.  The underscores get converted into bold text.  It should show double underscore init.py double underscore.

Answer (score 89):

A note for others who run into this: you need to restart the development server to register new files in your django app.

Comment: Well there's 20 minutes down the drain but you've saved me 20 more at any rate. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

My problem was due to a typo.  I called the file in templatetags `__init.py__` but it should have been named `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I was using a shared `templatetags` directory, and that didn't have the `__init__.py` in it.  Added that empty file in, restarted server, and all was well.